# Extract Date in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript

I would like to ask for your help on this. We implemented a feature where if we selected a date from a calendar, it will display the date that is selected. While we can display the right date, it is not in the right format. I need to extract the dates from this sample statement:
**EndDateTime=2021-05-29T02%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00T01%3A00%3A00.000Z,StartDateTime=2021-05-29T02%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00T00%3A00%3A00.000Z**

I need to extract the startdate and enddate using javascript. And it has to be in a DD-MMMM-YYYY format. Hopefully you can help me in here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would see if you can't get your output cleaned up a bit closer to the source. But since I am not familiar with your code, here's a method of extracting a date in the format `dd-MMMM-YYYY` from that string. Similar logic applies to the start date.

```js
let str = 'EndDateTime=2021-05-29T02%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00T01%3A00%3A00.000Z,StartDateTime=2021-05-29T02%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00T00%3A00%3A00.000Z';
let parts = str.split(',');
// extract only the date you want and remove the URI encoding
let endDateTimeStamp = decodeURIComponent(parts[1].split('=')[1]);

// generate a date, drop the time portion as it will result in an invalid date
let endDate = new Date(endDateTimeStamp.split('T')[0]);

// JavaScript doesn't have much in the way of built-in methods for formatting dates. This is one option.
let year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(endDate);
let month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'long' }).format(endDate);
let day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(endDate);

let formattedEndDate = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
console.log(formattedEndDate);
```

Refer to the documentation on [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format). If you have a locale (perhaps 'UK'?) that formats to `dd-MMMM-YYYY` then you may use that and eliminate the need to parse the date into individual components.